# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource can't be opened

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I work on Spring web MVC project and try to write some test for the database operations. The test class is provided below,

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/config/dao-context.xml",
//        "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/config/security-context.xml",
        "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/dao/test/config/datasource.xml"
})

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OfferDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private OffersDao offersDao;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        jdbc.execute("delete from offers");
        jdbc.execute("delete from users");
        jdbc.execute("delete from authorities");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {

        Offer offer = new Offer("johnwpurcell", "john@caveofprogramming.com", "This is a test offer.");

        assertTrue("Offer creation should return true", offersDao.create(offer));

        List<Offer> offers = offersDao.getOffers();

        assertEquals("Should be one offer in database.", 1, offers.size());

        assertEquals("Retrieved offer should match created offer.", offer, offers.get(0));

        // Get the offer with ID filled in.
        offer = offers.get(0);

        offer.setText("Updated offer text.");
        assertTrue("Offer update should return true", offersDao.update(offer));

        Offer updated = offersDao.getOffer(offer.getId());

        assertEquals("Updated offer should match retrieved updated offer", offer, updated);

        offersDao.delete(offer.getId());

        List<Offer> empty = offersDao.getOffers();

        assertEquals("Offers lists should be empty.", 0, empty.size());
    }
}
```

The project structure is provided below,

[image]

I get the error informing that the `datasource.xml` can't be opened, because, it doesn't exist. Its indeed exist and the path is correct as well.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/puut/bitcoin/dao/test/config/datasource.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
```

In the `datasource.xml` file, I see that the `Application context is not configured for this file` and `IntelliJ` is literally provided some option to do so.

[image]

This is not very clear to me as I have defined this file in the `OfferDaoTests` as following,

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
            "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/config/dao-context.xml",
    //        "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/config/security-context.xml",
            "classpath:com/puut/bitcoin/dao/test/config/datasource.xml"
    })
```

I don't see the point to define the file in the `web.xml` as well. Because, this is only to test the database operations. Also, suddenly gets some error in the `web.xml` which was not here a while ago. [image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: suppose `datasource.xml` is located in the test package which is you are not referring correctly

Comment: Is `test` on your classpath?

Comment: I take the `classpath` automatically `(CMD + ALT + SHIFT + C)` from the `IntellIJ` and appears to be correct. I have also tried to use the full class path from the `src`. It doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html), the `@ContextConfiguration` lookup the resources. So, you could create a `resource` folder, preferably under `/test` folder, with the structure `com/puut/bitcoin/dao/test/config/datasource.xml`. This way the spring configuration should be able to read the resources for your test. So, your folder structure should look like:

```
/test/java - contains your test cases
/test/resources - contains your XML/configuration files
```

Comment: Do you mean I Should put all inside the 'test/resources/' ?

Comment: I mean under `/test`. Like `test/java` contains your test cases and `test/resources` contains your XML files/resources.